# How can I convert string values from a dictionary, into int/float datatypes?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, integer

I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
list = [ { 'a':'1' , 'b':'2' , 'c':'3' }, { 'd':'4' , 'e':'5' , 'f':'6' } ]
```

How do I convert the values of each dictionary inside the list to int/float?

So it becomes:

```
list = [ { 'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3 }, { 'd':4 , 'e':5 , 'f':6 } ]
```

Comment: It is very much discouraged to name variables as builtin types. Hopefully this is just for the purposes of the example, but if not you should avoid this in your code.

Comment: Please fix your code from `list = [ { 'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3 }}, { 'd':4 , 'e':5 , 'f':6 } ]` to `list = [ { 'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3 }, { 'd':4 , 'e':5 , 'f':6 } ]`

Comment: @Guandalino: Just wrote the codes on the spot.. sorry abt that. editted.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
for sub in the_list:
    for key in sub:
        sub[key] = int(sub[key])
```

Gives it a casting as an int instead of as a string.

Comment: Haha, I was just changing that around, but yeah Jochen got it correctly, the whole naming your dictionary a list, confused me for a second.

Answer (score 54):

We have got to love [list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python).

```
[dict([a, int(x)] for a, x in b.items()) for b in list]
```

(*Remark: for Python 2-only code, you may use "iteritems" instead of "items"*)

Comment: pretty hard to digest though agreed impressive! How to deal with: ValueError: empty string for float() for floating and ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.6' for 'integering'?

Comment: eventually i wud like to do stats on the list items. (max, min, average, stdev)

Comment: You could write a function to replace the int() call in the comprehention to allow for all of the exeptions you desire.

Comment: Could be possible, but then i'd rather be using Perl :P

Answer (score 8):

If that's your exact format, you can go through the list and modify the dictionaries.

```
for item in list_of_dicts:
    for key, value in item.iteritems():
        try:
            item[key] = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            item[key] = float(value)
```

If you've got something more general, then you'll have to do some kind of recursive update on the dictionary. Check if the element is a dictionary, if it is, use the recursive update. If it's able to be converted into a float or int, convert it and modify the value in the dictionary. There isn't any built-in function for this and it can be quite ugly (and non-Pythonic since it usually requires calling isinstance).

Answer (score 2):

For [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3),

```
    for d in list:
        d.update((k, float(v)) for k, v in d.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd decide for a solution acting "in place" you could take a look at this one:

```
>>> d = [ { 'a':'1' , 'b':'2' , 'c':'3' }, { 'd':'4' , 'e':'5' , 'f':'6' } ]
>>> [dt.update({k: int(v)}) for dt in d for k, v in dt.iteritems()]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> d
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}]
```

Btw, key order is not preserved because that's the way standard dictionaries work, ie without the concept of order.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the possibility of `int`, `float`, and empty string values, I'd use a combination of a list comprehension, dictionary comprehension, along with conditional expressions, as shown:

```
dicts = [{'a': '1' , 'b': '' , 'c': '3.14159'},
         {'d': '4' , 'e': '5' , 'f': '6'}]

print [{k: int(v) if v and '.' not in v else float(v) if v else None
            for k, v in d.iteritems()}
               for d in dicts]

# [{'a': 1, 'c': 3.14159, 'b': None}, {'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}]
```

However dictionary comprehensions weren't added to Python 2 until version 2.7. It can still be done in earlier versions as a single expression, but has to be written using the `dict` constructor like the following:

```
# for pre-Python 2.7

print [dict([k, int(v) if v and '.' not in v else float(v) if v else None]
            for k, v in d.iteritems())
                for d in dicts]

# [{'a': 1, 'c': 3.14159, 'b': None}, {'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6}]
```

Note that either way this creates a new dictionary of lists, instead of modifying the original one in-place (which would need to be done differently).

Comment: could I edit the "v" on the spot if v='' , i.e. empty items? would try and see. thanks. helpful.

Comment: Regarding your question about handling empty "v" items: you could rewrite the `if` expression to deal with them as I've shown in my revised answer.

Comment: As to your second question about getting a syntax error at `... for k...`, dictionary comprehensions require Python 2.7+ or 3.1+, so using earlier versions could be causing the problem.

Comment: Follow up to my last comment: You could replace the `int(x)` in @Powertieke's answer with the conditional expression similar to what is in mine to get rid of the dictionary comprehension and result in something to use in earlier versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
  newlist = []              # Make an empty list
  for i in list:            # Loop to hv a dict in list
     s = {}                 # Make an empty dict to store new dict data
     for k in i.keys():     # To get keys in the dict of the list
         s[k] = int(i[k])   # Change the values from string to int by int func
     newlist.append(s)      # To add the new dict with integer to the list
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general way using [this number converter](https://gist.github.com/raczben/76cd1229504d82115e6427e00cf4742c#file-numrange-py-L3) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317657/2506522).

```
def number(a, just_try=False):
    try:
        # First, we try to convert to integer.
        # (Note, that all integers can be interpreted 
        #  as float and hexadecimal numbers.)
        return int(a)
    except:
        # The order of the following conversions doesn't matter.
        # The integer conversion has failed because `a` 
        # contains hexadecimal digits [x,a-f] or a 
        # decimal point ['.'], but not both.
        try:
            return int(a, 16)
        except:
            try:
                return float(a)
            except:
                if just_try:
                    return a
                else:
                    raise


# The conversion:
[dict([a, number(x)] for a, x in b.items()) for b in list]
```

This will handle integer, float, and hexadecimal formats.