# Python - converting string key to integer

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary in following order. This dictionary is dynamically generated using `from collections import defaultdict`

```
Ref = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'344': [('0', '0', '136'), 
('548', '136', '137'), 
('548', '136', '6')],        
'345': [('0', '0', '136'), ('548', '136', '137'), 
('548', '136', '6'), 
('742', '136', '6')]}
```

**What I tried:**

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193682/convert-a-string-key-to-int-in-a-dictionary)

```
Ref = {int(k):[int(i) for i in v] for k,v in Ref.items()}
```

but i get an error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

**What I want:**

I want to convert all keys and values which are in string to integers like

```
Ref = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {344: [(0, 0, 136), 
    (548, 136, 137), 
    (548, 136, 6)],        
    345: [(0, 0, 136), (548, 136, 137), 
    (548, 136, 6), 
    (742, 136, 6)]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your values are list and the items are tuple you need to convert the tuples items to `int`,you can use `map` function for that  :

```
Ref = {int(k):[map(int,i) for i in v] for k,v in Ref.items()}
```

And if you are in python 3 you can use a generator expression within `tuple` :

```
Ref = {int(k):[tuple(int(t) for t in i) for i in v] for k,v in Ref.items()}
```

Also since `map` returns a list if you want the result be a tuple you can use this recipe too.

Comment: This works for Python 2 but not Python 3 where `map()` returns an iterable.

Comment: This is short and sweet. thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, I added the alternative!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert the key *and the tuples in the value*. Your question title suggests you want to convert just the key:

```
Ref = {int(key): value for key, value in Ref.items()}
```

This leaves the value untouched. Note that this replaces the `defaultdict` instance with a new plain `dict` object.

Your output suggests you also want to convert the values in the tuples to integers. Loop over the tuples too:

```
Ref = {int(key): [tuple(int(i) for i in t) for t in value]
       for key, value in Ref.items()}
```

Now each tuple in the list value is also processed, but each string *in the tuple* is converted to an integer, rather than trying to convert the whole tuple object to an integer.