# putting int/float from file into a dictionary

Tags: python, type-conversion

I like to put some values from a csv file into a dict. An example is:

```
TYPE, Weldline

Diam, 5.0

Num of Elems, 4
```

and I end up after reading into a dictionary (for later use in an API) in:

```
 {'TYPE':'Weldline' , 'Diam':'5.0','Num of Elems':'4'}
```

Since the API expects a dictionary i provided all the necessary keywords like 'TYPE', 'Diam', ... according to the API doc.

The problem I have is, that the API expects a float for `Diam` and an integer for `Num of Elems`

Since I have a large number of entries: is there an simple automatic way for string conversion into float or int?
Or do I have to write something on my own?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316720/python-how-to-convert-a-list-of-dictionaries-values-into-int-float-from-string

Comment: Provide keywords in form of dictionary where you link keyword to function that will convert value.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think the question is: How best to determine whether to use `int` or `float`?

Comment: @tobias_k aahh that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval`

> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

```
import ast

_dict = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            key, value = line.split(',')
            value = value.strip()
            try:
                _dict[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
            except ValueError:
                _dict[key] = value

print _dict
```

Comment: It's better to suggest `ast.literal_eval` than `eval`. I did not down-vote you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this it seems more simple.

```
import csv,ast
    with open('file.csv', mode='r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    mydict = {rows[0]:ast.literal_eval(rows[1]) for rows in reader}
print mydict
```

Comment: Does not work, the "strings" in the file are not quoted.

Comment: Thats what i found also... so any other idea?

Comment: @Bruno See turkus answer: `try` to evaluate the string, and if that does not work, just take it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Now I tried this:

```
                key   = Line[0].strip()
                value = Line[1].strip()
                try:
                    value = int(Line[1].strip())
                except ValueError:
                    try: 
                        value = float(Line[1].strip())
                    except ValueError:
                        value = Line[1].strip()

            Entry[key]=value
```

It seems it works fine...