# How can I use `map` in python to convert dict values to integers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert dictionary keys (from `json.loads()`) to ints with `map()`.  I know I can do this with loops, but I'm trying to do it functionally so I can implement it in spark.  For example:

```
import pyspark as ps
import json

# Uses all 4 cores on your machine
sc = ps.SparkContext('local[4]')

file_rdd = sc.textFile('data/cookie_data.txt')
kv_rdd_json = file_rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
kv_rdd2 = kv_rdd_json.map(lambda x: map(int, x.get)) # here's the issue
kv_rdd.collect()
```

I have another way to do it with a function, but I'm curious: how can I do it with .map in pyspark (and python2, bonus for python3)?

Per the comments:
example data (plaintext):

```
{"Jane": "2"}
{"Jane": "1"}
{"Pete": "20"}
{"Tyler": "3"}
{"Duncan": "4"}
{"Yuki": "5"}
{"Duncan": "6"}
{"Duncan": "4"}
{"Duncan": "5"}
```

example of how to convert dict values to int:
[Python: How to convert a list of dictionaries' values into int/float from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316720/python-how-to-convert-a-list-of-dictionaries-values-into-int-float-from-string)

```
for key in mydict.keys():
    mydict[key] = int(mydict[key])
```

The .get is kind of like here: [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Please provide the content of your dict

Comment: can you provide a `cookie_data.txt` sample? Or even better, the `ps.SparkContext()` output

Comment: [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) takes at least two arguments, a function and iterables to which to apply the function, and it returns a list.   `int` is a function, but what is `x.get`?

Comment: You can still write your own function as pass that into `map`. That function just need to accept a dictionary parameter

Comment: If you only want the keys of the dictionary as integers, then you are looking for `map(int, x.keys())`

Comment: You say you know how to do it with a loop. Perhaps if your showed the loop, we could better understand what you want and provide an alternate method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dict(zip(mydict, map(int, mydict.values())))
```

Or with lambda:

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1])), mydict.items()))
```