# convert dict(with integer value) to json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have used a `dataframe` with country and service data to count the recurrence of service grouped by country and generated the dictionary d. I have been trying to convert the `dict` into `json` since `dict` type is not callable. But it is giving the following `error`. What can be done to change the `int64` into string?

```
TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried :

```
d = {'India': {'A': 1, 'C': 2}, 'Malaysia': {'B': 1, 'A': 1, 'D': 1}, 'Croatia': {'C': 1}}
y = json.dumps(d)
return y
```

Comment: I copy&pasted your code example to my python console and it worked (except return because it isn't in a method).

Comment: The code you posted [doesn't produce this error](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGrOD@PK0XBVqFa3TMvJTNR3QrIcgSShjoK6s5A2qgWyPBNzEmsLIbKOkFlYapcQDRIlXNRfmIJVJEzWLCWi6sSaDbIEr2U0tyCYo0Uzf//AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try it using a method. Because the use case is, taking data from excel sheet, converting into dataframe, dataframe into the dictionary, that into json . This is done in Flask framework. API is unable to call json with int64 value in it

Answer (score 0):

Did you import json ? because following is working just fine

```
import json
d = {'India': {'A': 1, 'C': 2}, 'Malaysia': {'B': 1, 'A': 1, 'D': 1},               
'Croatia': {'C': 1}}

y = json.dumps(d)
print(type(y))
```

Comment: yes i did, this wont return a json file since integer value in the dict d, cannot be converted into json

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to serialize data that is numpy data of type int64. You'll need to convert data to python integers first.

Modifying the answers here should work: [How to convert string values from a dictionary, into int/float datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316720/how-to-convert-string-values-from-a-dictionary-into-int-float-datatypes)

EDIT: You can convert all entries to a string as follows:

```
import json

d = {'India': {'A': 1, 'C': 2}, 'Malaysia': {'B': 1, 'A': 1, 'D': 1}, 'Croatia': {'C': 1}}

for country_dict in d.values():
    for key in country_dict:
        country_dict[key] = str(country_dict[key])

y = json.dumps(d)
```

Comment: i need to convert int to str, i used 
for s in d.values():
    for sn in s.values():
        sn=str(sn)

its still not converting

Comment: It's the same principle as described in the solutions linked. Just change `int(sub[key])` to `str(sub[key])`

Comment: it still doesnt work. can we convert the dictionary d into a Multilevel dataframe and then convert it into json?

Comment: I have edited my original response with code to convert the dictionary entries to strings.

Comment: this does not work either when this code is a method and if i am trying to 'RETURN' json, still gives the same numpy.int64 error

Comment: Your function just has to `return y` at the end. I can't help any further without seeing the rest of your code, there must be int64s somewhere in the dictionary that you're trying to `json.dumps()`.